# How to input char data to tensorflow rnn cell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is my model:

```
rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(512)
m_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn_cell]*3, state_is_tuple = False)
prediction, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(m_rnn_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

error = tf.reduce_mean((labels - prediction)**2
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)
```

X is the placeholder I use to input data. I want to train it using a few English sentences. How do I do that? How do I shape my data, labels and placeholders? Can you also provide the code to train it?

Comment: what have you done as far as trying to write the code to train it?

Comment: If you'd like an example of implementing an RNN you can talk a look at this example https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow/blob/master/solutions/07-rnn.py or alternatively try following the tensorflow RNN example.